# Last input in Counterclockwise REPL?

Tags: eclipse, clojure, read-eval-print-loop, counterclockwise

Is it possible to go through a history of what you've typed into the Counterclockwise REPL in Eclipse? Like pressing the up-arrow or ctrl-p or various other things that work in other repls?
Thanks!
-Philip

Answer (score 17):

Yes, sorry for not having  taken the time to document everything.

What you're after is Ctrl+UP / Ctrl+DOWN keys.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work on my OS X Snow Leopard machine. Any ideas?

Comment: @Phil Probably Cmd-up and Cmd-down. I don't use a mac, but my experience has been that where other systems use Ctl, the Mac uses Cmd (eg Cmd-C to copy).

Comment: I'm also on a Mac. Neither Cmd, Control, nor anything other modifier I try works. :(

Comment: I'm on OSX Snow Leopard and I can confirm that ctrl+up /ctrl+down works.

Comment: On OS X Lion & Counterclockwise 0.12.1.STABLE001, Ctrl+p/Ctrl+n seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

For Counterclockwise version 0.8.0.STABLE001 I was able to use the standard Eclipse "Keys" preferences screen to redefine "Load next command from REPL's history" in the "In Clojure REPL" category to Cmd-Up thus getting the requested functionality to work in Eclipse Indigo on Mac OS X Lion.

Answer (score 0):

Testing on Counterclockwise version: **0.34.0.STABLE001**
OS version: **OSX El Capitan 10.11.6**

Placing your cursor in the REPL command window that presents with `<type Clojure code here>` and:

Pressing <kbd>control + p</kbd> will navigate to the *previous* command in history.

Pressing <kbd>control + n</kbd> will navigate to the *next* command in history.

As comments on previous answers indicate this is different on a windows version of Counterclockwise.